# MS Access "record changes" log

Tags: ms-access, vba

Whenever a record is deleted or updated on a form, I want to save its old values in a history table (let's call it Revised). I guess I have to do the following:

*For record changes*:

- use the BeforeUpdate event to save the data *somewhere* (collection ? array ? or to a recordset -the Revised table- without saving-yet ?)
- use the AfterUpdate event to add/save that data to the Revised table

*For Deletions*:

- use the OnDelete event to save the data - but again how ? several records could be deleted at once since the form (a subform in fact) is in datasheet view
- use the AfterDelConfirm to add that data to the Revised table.

Do you have any clues, comments or links for this ?
This is all in a "pure Access" (no SQL Server) at the moment.
Many thanks !

---

Edit: as usual, properly asking the question gaves me ideas:

- **option 1**
  use the BeforeUpdate or the OnDelete to build the SQL statement, and use the AfterUpdate or the AfterDelConfirm to Execute the SQL statement. But that won't work for multiple deletions ?
- **option 2**
  have the Revised recordset defined at form level, insert the record "Before" but only Update "After". Again, problem with multiple deletes.

Comment: what is usually done (and easy to manage) is to keep a log of sql INSERTs, UPDATEs or DELETEs. But I guess you are working here with recordsets which are bound to controls\forms, aren't you? By the way, what do you want to track exactly? Modifications on all tables? a few tables? specific fields? per user?

Comment: @Philippe G: I want to track all changes (deletes or updates, I see no reason to track inserts) for 1 specific table

Comment: Thinking about your problem, by tracking the original INSERT, you will spare the necessity to follow the old/new value on each update. The initial INSERT will give you the original 'old' value, while the last UPDATE will give you the newest value.

Comment: Some references: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/197592   and http://www.ofnisystems.com/index.htm (quoted on tek-tips.com by phv)

Comment: Another thing to consider up front is if/how you will present this audit trail to users.  It's incredibly difficult to end up with a solution that is flexible, concise, and easy for users to understand.  You generally have to pick the two most important attributes from that list and sacrifice the third.  That decision will impact your entire design, so it's important to figure that out up front.

Comment: Would it help to re-define the concept of "deleted" to something like "active"?  The form's record source could include `WHERE active = True`  And deletions actually become `active = False`  Seems like this could be an inexpensive way to maintain a history of deleted records --- they're still present, but just not visible in the form.

Comment: +1 to @HansUp for the idea of "marking" records deleted, rather than actually deleting them.  As storage gets cheaper, I'm reconsidering what I should really be deleting.  As long as you can maintain performance, it's nice to be able to tell users, "Oh, you didn't mean to delete those records?  Actually, yes, I can get them back for you."

Comment: about the Active record concept: that's really good, but... since a boolean field has little benefit being indexed, I am afraid that it would slow down the whole thing, since every query should add an  `Active = True`  condition, and by this, more or less force a table scan.

Comment: instead of an `IsActive` field, you could have a `DateDeleted` field.  It eats up a bit more storage space, but it could be indexed and would also provide additional information (which might be helpful someday when trying to figure out exactly what a user was doing).  Every query would then have a `DateDeleted Is Null` condition, instead of `Active = True`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've successfully used a variation of Allen Browne's approach in a couple of different projects.  Check out his website for more details:

[Creating an Audit Log](http://allenbrowne.com/AppAudit.html)

His solution uses temp tables and four generic function calls to handle the issue with multiple deletes.

Comment: Excellent Allen Browne ! His site is a goldmine !

Answer (score 3):

Another approach I have considered more recently, but have not had an opportunity to actually implement, would be to use transactions to perform the change tracking.  The basic algorithm would be:

1. use BeginTrans on the workspace prior to making any changes
2. in the OnDelete event

   - perform the deletions in code executing Delete queries against the workspace from step 1
   - add a record to your change auditing table
3. in the BeforeDelConfirm event

   - set Cancel = True
   - display your own Confirmation dialog
   - if user confirms then CommitTrans on workspace
   - otherwise Rollback the transaction on the workspace

Similar approach for Updates/Inserts.  This would avoid the need for temporary tables/arrays/collections, etc. but I haven't fully thought through everything.  The devil may be in the details.

Comment: +1 for both your suggestions.  I'm put off by the challenge of integrating them with the case where multiple records selected in the datasheet view are deleted as a single operation.  Any thoughts on that aspect?

Comment: Actually both solutions address the issue.  From Allen's site: *In the form's Delete event, the code below writes a copy of the record to the temp table. In the form's AfterDelConfirm event, these records are copied into the true audit table only if the Status argument provided by Access indicates that the deletion proceeded. The copies in the temp table are then removed.*

Comment: And actually, the algorithm in this answer is meant to address that same issue.  By setting Cancel=True in the OnDelete you are taking deletion duties away from the bound form so they may be performed against the open transaction.  This then allows you to roll back the transaction (both the deletions themselves and the additions to the change history) if the user cancels out of that delete.

Comment: Edit: I just tested this and realized the BeforeDelConfirm/AfterDelConfirm events don't run if all of the Delete events are canceled.  So I moved the Cancel=True to the BeforeDelConfirm event.

Comment: The one other issue is when to actually call the BeginTrans.  I sort of glossed over that in my answer, but the order of events is **Delete** → **BeforeDelConfirm** → **AfterDelConfirm**.  That means there is no event to BeginTrans prior to the first Delete event.  As I said, the devil may be in the details...

Comment: I didn't express my thought well or you addressed it and I'm just not grokking it.  Either way, my bad.  When the user is deleting only the current record, it's easy to identify *which record*.  Then do something instead of, or in addition to, simple deletion.  But when multiple records are selected for one delete operation, you need to identify them.  That's the challenge which puts me off.  IIRC, you can inspect the form's SelTop and SelHeight, but those are no longer available when focus shifts to a different control.  So is there a simple flexible alternative to identify the selected rows?

Comment: The Delete form event runs once *for each record* being deleted.  So if the user selects 5 records and presses the Delete key, then Form_Delete is called 5 times, then Form_BeforeDelConfirm is called once, then Form_AfterDelConfirm is called once.  Canceling all of the Form_Delete's (`Cancel=True`) can prevent the Form_BeforeDelConfirm from running.  Likewise, canceling the Form_BeforeDelConfirm can prevent the Form_AfterDelConfirm from running.

Comment: It would be nice if Access raised a second Delete event for each record in between the BeforeDelConfirm and AfterDelConfirm events.  It would make this sort of thing easier to deal with.

Comment: Thank you @mwolfe02 ... "The Delete form event runs once for each record being deleted."  I somehow had myself convinced otherwise.  :-(

Answer (score 0):

An "easy" and generic solution, which could be implemented for multiple tables, would be to have a tracking table, made of the following:

```
Track_Table
==================================================
id_track as primary key
id_table as name of the table which has been updated
id_primaryKey as the record identifier (the PK of the updated record)
changeType, being either DEL or UPDATE
changeDate, as dateTime value
fieldName, as text
oldValue, as text or memo
newValue, as text or memo
```

if you have to identify the user who did the update, just add

```
userId
```

in your table ...

You could then create some generic "before update" and "after update functions" to be called on selected form's beforeUpdate and afterUpdate events. The beforeUpdate fonction will store the old value in a variable, while the afterUpdate function will populate the missing data and insert a new record in the track table.

You will have to find a way to find out the right\corresponding table name and field name. This could be difficult if you are using views or field aliases to display your data in forms.

Of course, all tables to be followed must have a primary key so you can follow changes at the record level. PKs set on multiple fields will surely be problematic ....

oldValues and newValues will have to be converted as text so you can store them in a text or memo field